# Inno setup Filename copy files after check

Tags: inno-setup

I am new with Inno Setup and now I have some problems. My setup is working so far, that I have a wizard and installing after the wizard somes executables.

Now is my problem:

I want to copy a folder, after asking the user if he wants to install it. This I realise over a check. The copy does work (it also works if the user says "No" --> so nothing is copied) , but I get an error, because he cannot read the file. What is the right way to copy a text file in this case?

After this is working instead of a txt file a whole folder should be copied this way. Do you have ideas?

```
[Files]
Source: "{folder\test.txt";   DestDir: "{tmp}\MIKTEX"; 
[Run:]
Filename: "temp\test.text"; StatusMsg: Installing Miktex; Check:checkMiktexInstall();
```

I think the part with the `Filename` is the problem. Have somebody a idea? I also tried to do the check in the `Files` section at the end, but this does not copy the files.

Best Wishes,
BG

Comment: What's the purpose of your `[Run]` section entry?

Comment: There are also the rules for the exe-files, where to install them and what to do after and beforinstallation of them.

Comment: Also, in your script you have `test.txt` and then `test.text`. And `[Run:]` is not valid. Have you tried compiling this in Inno Setup and looked at the build output?

Comment: This with test.text is only a example from me because of make it anonymous of my working files. I also tried to make Filename: "{temp}\Miktex" and also the whole path the user can choose and then +test.txt, but eyerytime it says, that it cannot excecute or read the file.

Comment: Or is there any other (better)  way to copy the file, after I asked the user if he wishes to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now in an other way. I made a procedure, where i checked the users choice and if said yes, then it calls an other function, where the files are copied. This first procedure I call in the Run-Part after the installation of a exe-file with the "AfterInstall"-call.